# How to change free jqfrid font size of toolbar search box

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am able to change the font size of the cell content by using :

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

But this does not change the font size of the text in the toolbar search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding CSS rules can be the following

```css
.ui-jqgrid  .ui-search-toolbar .ui-search-table {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-toolbar input,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-toolbar select {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

The first rule set the font size of searching operations and the clear character ("x") and the second rule set the font size of the input and select elements of the searching toolbar.